# How to show only 5 results of a list in jinja, returning results from flask?

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

I am new to jinja2. I am getting all records from DB using flask as `results` list. But i want to show only 5 records.

I tried like this -

```
{% for result in results[5] %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ result[0] }}</td>
                <td>{{ result[1] }}</td>
                <td>{{ result[2] }}</td>
            </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

But its not working.

Can anyone help me to resolve this ?

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: change `results[5]` to `results[:5]`

Comment: @BrunoCarballo Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `results[5]`, it's just considering the 5th element. If you need to consider the first 5 elements, you have to do `results[:5]`

Comment: Thank you so much.